# Group by нескольких полей

Tags: sqlite, android, sql

Есть контакты номеров в БД.
У некоторых имен есть несколько номеров.
Как мне сгруппировать и по имени и по номеру, 
чтобы на выходе был каждый номер и у каждого номера было имя рядом?

Делаю так, но похоже, что неправильно:

```
select name, number, count(fer) from calllog group by number;
```

Что здесь неправильно?

Comment: Если нужен номер и имя, то просто:

select name, number from calllog order by number;

Или покажите, какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: Мне нужен count по группе, 
чтобы на выходе было группировка только номера и чтобы у каждой группы был номер и имя, а также count,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by number, name.

В выборке должны быть или поля, по которым производится группировка, или агрегирующие функции

Comment: 
select name, number, count(fer) from calllog group by  name, number;

правильно ли так?
что здесь происходит, сначала группировка по имени и потом делит эти группы еще на группы по номеру, 
правильно ли порядок?

Comment: Если номер может принадлежать только одному name, то count() везде будет давать 1.
Еще раз. Приведите пример данных, и результат, который вы хотите получить.

О группировке можно почитать здесь: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_group_by_clause.html

Comment: Когда я так делаю, выходит, что если так писать, он не выдает имя, а только номера,